# WPF Bing Maps and Manipulation, how to disable rotation but leave the zoom/pan functionality

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I am using the WPF Bing Maps SDK and it's working great. However by default on touch screens, the map is manipulate-able (much like how by default the scroll wheel zooms and click-pulling pans the map). This is fine except the map allows rotation, which we want to specifically disallow. Is there a way to explicitly disable rotation? If not, I know there are several manipulation events I can hook handlers on to. However, if I hook a handler, do I end up overriding the default zoom/pan/rotate handler? If I write a handler do I have to implement the entire manipulation functionality again? Or is there an event where I can just check the rotation angle and re-set it to 0 on every manipulation? If that's the case, what event should I listen for? Manipulation Starting, or Manipulation Started?

Answer (score 1):

This was very trivial and now I feel embarrassed to be answering my own question.

Bing maps allows specification of what manipulation is allowed through the following property:

SupportedManipulations="Translate,Scale"